# concurrentmodificationexception hashmap in java

Tags: java

I write following code but when this run it generate concurrentmodificationexception

```
if( attendancePolicy.getType().equals( AttendanceConstants.EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE_POLICY ) ) {
    synchronized( attendancePolicy.getListEmployee() ) {
        for( EmployeeAttendancePolicy employeeAttendancePolicy : attendancePolicy.getListEmployee() ) {
            employeeInfo = employeeInfoSessionBeanLocal.findEmployeeInfoEntityByEmployeeInfoId( 
                    employeeAttendancePolicy.getEmployeeId() );

            if( employeeInfo != null ) {
                employeeAttendancePolicy.setEmpName( 
                        employeeInfo.getFirstName() + " " 
                        + employeeInfo.getMiddleName() + " "
                        + employeeInfo.getLastName() );

                company = companySessionBeanLocal.findCompanyById( employeeInfo.getCompanyId() );
                employeeAttendancePolicy.setCompanyName( company.getName() );

                department = departmentSessionBeanLocal.findDepartmentEntityByDepartmentId( 
                        employeeInfo.getDepartmentId() );
                employeeAttendancePolicy.setDepartmentName( department.getName() );
            }
            else {
                attendancePolicy.getListEmployee().remove( employeeAttendancePolicy );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConcurrentModificationException` is caused by the fact that you are using an `Iterator` over a `List`, and you are then modifying that `List`.

See the `Iterator` Java doc page - http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html, you could use the `remove` method of the `Iterator` to avoid this:

> Removes from the underlying collection
>   the last element returned by the
>   iterator (optional operation). This
>   method can be called only once per
>   call to next. The behavior of an
>   iterator is unspecified if the
>   underlying collection is modified
>   while the iteration is in progress in
>   any way other than by calling this
>   method.

Rewrite your code to this:

```
if( attendancePolicy.getType().equals( AttendanceConstants.EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE_POLICY ) ) {
    synchronized( attendancePolicy.getListEmployee() ) {

        // Explicitly create the Iterator and loop condition
        for( Iterator<EmployeeAttendancePolicy> it = 
attendancePolicy.getListEmployee().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {

            // Explicitly declare the looping variable
            EmployeeAttendancePolicy employeeAttendancePolicy = it.next(); 

            employeeInfo = employeeInfoSessionBeanLocal.findEmployeeInfoEntityByEmployeeInfoId( 
                    employeeAttendancePolicy.getEmployeeId() );

            if( employeeInfo != null ) {
                employeeAttendancePolicy.setEmpName( 
                        employeeInfo.getFirstName() + " " 
                        + employeeInfo.getMiddleName() + " "
                        + employeeInfo.getLastName() );

                company = companySessionBeanLocal.findCompanyById( employeeInfo.getCompanyId() );
                employeeAttendancePolicy.setCompanyName( company.getName() );

                department = departmentSessionBeanLocal.findDepartmentEntityByDepartmentId( 
                        employeeInfo.getDepartmentId() );
                employeeAttendancePolicy.setDepartmentName( department.getName() );
            }
            else {

                // Use the Iterator's remove method to safely remove
                // thus avoiding the ConcurrentModificationException
                it.remove();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're removing `employeeAttendancePolicy` from the list employee from within a for-loop that is iterating over the list employee collection. That is the "concurrent" operation that has caused the exception.

If you want to remove something from inside a loop, you need to revert to a "regular" iterator loop (not the "enhanced" for loop above). Something like this perhaps:

```
Iterator<EmployeeAttendancePolicy> iter = attendancePolicy.getListEmployee();
while (iter.hasNext())
{
  EmployeeAttendancePolicy employeeAttendancePolicy = iter.next();

  //... somewhere in here when you decide to remove
  iter.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing an item from the list you are iterating over.

One way to resolve this is to add the item to remove to a new collection, and then, when you have completed the first loop, remove those items from the list.

e.g. something like

```
        synchronized (attendancePolicy.getListEmployee()) {
            Set toRemove = new HashSet();

            for(EmployeeAttendancePolicy employeeAttendancePolicy : attendancePolicy.getListEmployee()){

                employeeInfo=employeeInfoSessionBeanLocal.findEmployeeInfoEntityByEmployeeInfoId(employeeAttendancePolicy.getEmployeeId());

                if(employeeInfo!=null){
                    ...
                }else{
                    toRemove.add(employeeAttendancePolicy);
                }

            }
            attendancePolicy.getListEmployee().removeAll(toRemove);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ConcurrentHashMap and CopyOnWriteArrayList. These collections are designed to be used when multiple thread are working on collections.